# How to map exotic Unicode Latin alphabets to their base letters?

Tags: unicode, mapping, non-ascii-characters

I need to map far-out Unicode Latin substitutes to their respective base letters.

```
    — should match 4× “Overflow”
```

These examples from [Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D400.pdf) already comprise considerable variants, but there’s the [Enclosed Alphanumeric Supplement](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F100.pdf) and of course [Halfwidth and Fullwidth Forms](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFF00.pdf), and a vast lot more, so there’s no point to write up a mapping manually.

It’s not about diacritics (as in questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639086/) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024072/), more like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293909/)). I also don’t want to merely *test* for occurence, so even with support, [`\p{Symbol}`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category) wouldn’t help.

If I was looking for a `U+0041 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A`, I want to also match `U+1D49C MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT CAPITAL A` as well as `U+FF21 FULLWIDTH LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A` and also, say, every other derivative with “[LATIN] LETTER A” in it.

Is there some sort of attributes to Unicode code points, pointing to a possible base character they were derived from, and to to evaluate it programmatically (T-SQL, .NET)?

Comment: What language are you looking for a solution in? (Though as long as it supports unicode normalization, you can easily adapt the python answer already given...)

Comment: Compatibility Normalization Form links the character to the "real" one. Note: formatting strings should be done changing the fonts, not changing unicode characters. It may be ok for lettering (and logos, and similar) use, but so I recommend against do it programmatically.